# How to increase the text limit for withdrawal in Langchain?

Tags: javascript, langchain

I'm trying to get a big answer from Openai, but in the answer I get a text length of no more than 400 characters, although it is clear that Openai continues to write, but the answer comes only part of it.

I can't find anywhere how to increase this limit.

```
import {OpenAI} from 'langchain/llms/openai'
import {RetrievalQAChain} from 'langchain/chains'
import {HNSWLib} from 'langchain/vectorstores/hnswlib'
import {OpenAIEmbeddings} from 'langchain/embeddings/openai'
import {RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter} from 'langchain/text_splitter'

// Loaders
import { DirectoryLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/directory";
import { JSONLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/json";
import { TextLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/text";
import { CSVLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/csv";
import { PDFLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf";

import { config } from "dotenv";
import { Document } from "langchain/document";

config();


// Read data useing directory loader
const loader = new DirectoryLoader("./text", {
    ".json": (path) => new JSONLoader(path),
    ".txt": (path) => new TextLoader(path,),
    ".csv": (path) => new CSVLoader(path, { separator: "|" }),
    ".pdf": (path) => new PDFLoader(path),
});

// See contents of docs that are being being loaded
const docs = await loader.load();
const csvContent = docs.map((doc) => doc.pageContent);


const askModel = async (question) => {
    const model = new OpenAI({ openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY , temperature: 0, stream: true});
    let vectorStore;

    const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
        chunkSize: 1000,
        chunkOverlap: 200,
    });

    const splitDocs = await textSplitter.createDocuments(csvContent);

    vectorStore = await HNSWLib.fromDocuments(
        splitDocs,
        new OpenAIEmbeddings()
    );

    await vectorStore.save("MyVectore.index");
    
    // Add a prompt before the actual question
    const prompt = "Use text from the document, ";
    const fullQuestion = `${prompt} ${question}`;

    // RetrievalQAChain
    const chain = RetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(model, vectorStore.asRetriever());

    const res = await chain.call({ query: fullQuestion, stream: true });
    
    console.log(res);
};

askModel(`write a text about (Movies about bodyguards) text length from 1000 characters`);
```